# git: says remote branch does not exist when it does

Tags: git

I have a git repository with two branches: `main` and `dev`, and a remote named `origin`. Both branches are set up to track their respective remote branches, and both branches are up-to-date, however only `main` says "Your branch is up to date". When I run `git branch --set-upstream-to origin/dev` I get the error `fatal: the requested upstream branch 'origin/dev' does not exist`.

`main` says "Your branch is up to date":

```bash
$ git checkout main
Switched to branch 'main'
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/main'.
```

`dev` does not:

```bash
$ git checkout dev
Switched to branch 'dev'
```

Even though it is tracking the remote:

```bash
$ git push -u origin dev
branch 'dev' set up to track 'origin/dev'.
Everything up-to-date

$ git status
On branch dev
nothing to commit, working tree clean
```

`--set-upstream-to` gives a fatal error, even though when I look on Github the branch definitely exists:

```bash
$ git branch --set-upstream-to origin/dev
fatal: the requested upstream branch 'origin/dev' does not exist
```

I try to fetch `origin/dev`:

```bash
$ git fetch origin dev
From https://github.com/raineorshine/myrepo
 * branch            dev         -> FETCH_HEAD
```

But `dev` does not show up in the remote branches:

```bash
git branch -r
  origin/HEAD -> origin/main
  origin/main
```

I have read the documentation for `git push -u` and `git branch --set-upstream-to` and I appear to be doing everything as instructed. What could be wrong? Thank you.

Comment: I would think that the commands that you wrote in the question are _not_ in the order you ran them. After `git push origin dev`, the branch should show up in `git branch -r` and you should be able to use it with `git branch --set-upstream`. Just in case, it would be redundant because you used `git push -u` which sets the upstream, Make sure of the order of the command _and_ if you still get the error, please, post the whole chain of commands and responses in the question as an update.

Comment: If there's no mistake in the way you describe the steps you took, it's indeed an unexpected behaviour. After that fruitful fetch the `dev` branch should definitely appear in `git branch -r` output, verbose or not.

Comment: From the information in front of me, I would think the flow was like this: you have a local `dev` branch, it does not exist in the remote. Then you tried to set the upstream, it does not work. Then you tried `git push -u` which created the branch in the remote (and also set it as your local branch's upstream).

Comment: @eftshift0 ...but even then it would show up in `git branch -vr` output. OP will probably tell us more.

Comment: Hmm... interesting indeed.

Comment: I have tried all the commands multiple times to be sure. After running `git push origin dev`, it successfully pushes and says `branch 'dev' set up to track 'origin/dev'`. Then I run `git branch -r` and `dev` **does not** show up.

Comment: When I do a fresh clone of the repo, the problem does not occur. However, if I do a **shallow clone** of the repo I get into a similar situation. `dev` is missing from the branch list even after `git fetch --unshallow`. I'm not sure if the original repo was a shallow clone but it seems likely.

Answer (score 1):

I had forgotten that the repo was a [shallow clone](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-clone#Documentation/git-clone.txt---depthltdepthgt).

I fixed it with `set-branches`:

```
git remote set-branches --add origin dev
```

My mistake, but I have to say git was a bit misleading in this particular circumstance.